# how to open a database access 2007

Tags: database, microsoft-access-2007

I would like to know how to open a database access.
To see the form. I'm sorry I forgot it. 
I can remember it is something like you have to press the CTRL or ALT or SHIFT together but not really sure what combination
Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold Shift and double click the file to open it in Design Mode

Comment: that's Shift only?